# Type error: file_name_extension/3 `character_code' expected , found `row(1, 410021001, 'Alan', 90, 84.5, 117, 60, 66)' (a compound)

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog-for-sharing

I am trying to read a csv file with this data format:
NO,ID,Name,HW1,HW2,HW3,Midterm,Final
1,410021001,Alan,90,84.5,117,60,66
2,410021002,Bob,85,49,80,57,64
..............................
This is my code:

```
%This is a prolog version of _410921334_hw2.py
% read data from file HW2data.csv and calculate the score of each student
% read data from file HW2data.csv row by row
% first row is the headings
% file structure: line_number,ID,Name,HW1,HW2,HW3,Midterm,Final
% round each grade to it's nearest whole number then,
% calculate the score of each student
% Score = HW1 * 0.1 + HW2 * 0.1 + HW3 * 0.1 + Midterm * 0.3 + Final * 0.4 -> round to nearest integer
% print the score of each student
% also print the grade for each student
% print format: StudentID    Name    Score   Grade
% A+ = 90-100, A = 85-89, A- = 80-84, B+ = 77-79, B = 73-76, B- = 70-72, C+ = 67-69, C= 63-66, C- = 60-62, D = 50-59, E = 0-49

%import SWI-Prolog's csv_read_file_row/3
:- use_module(library(csv)).
test :- augment('HW2data.csv', 'test.out.csv').
 
% augment( +InFileName, +OutFileName) 
% read data from InFileName 
% calculate score and grade for each student
% write the result to OutFileName
augment(InFileName, OutFileName) :-
    %read data from InFileName and save in appropriate variables
    csv_read_file(InFileName, [_|Rows], []),
    open(OutFileName, write, OutStream),
    write(OutStream, 'StudentID,Name,Score,Grade'), nl(OutStream),
    augment(Rows, OutStream),
    close(OutStream).    

% augment( +Rows, +OutStream)
% calculate score and grade for each student
% write the result to OutStream
augment([], _).
augment([row(_, ID, Name, HW1, HW2, HW3, Midterm, Final)|Rows], OutStream) :-
    Score is round(HW1 * 0.1 + HW2 * 0.1 + HW3 * 0.1 + Midterm * 0.3 + Final * 0.4),
    Grade is grade(Score),
    write(OutStream, ID), write(OutStream, ','),
    write(OutStream, Name), write(OutStream, ','),
    write(OutStream, Score), write(OutStream, ','),
    write(OutStream, Grade), nl(OutStream),
    augment(Rows, OutStream).  
  
% grade( +Score)
% return the grade for the score
grade(Score, Grade) :-
    Score >= 90, !, Grade = 'A+'.
grade(Score, Grade) :-
    Score >= 85, !, Grade = 'A'.
grade(Score, Grade) :-
    Score >= 80, !, Grade = 'A-'.
grade(Score, Grade) :-
    Score >= 77, !, Grade = 'B+'.
grade(Score, Grade) :-
    Score >= 73, !, Grade = 'B'.
grade(Score, Grade) :-
    Score >= 70, !, Grade = 'B-'.
grade(Score, Grade) :-
    Score >= 67, !, Grade = 'C+'.
grade(Score, Grade) :-
    Score >= 63, !, Grade = 'C'.
grade(Score, Grade) :-
    Score >= 60, !, Grade = 'C-'.
grade(Score, Grade) :-
    Score >= 50, !, Grade = 'D'.
grade(Score, Grade) :-
    Score < 50, !, Grade = 'E'.
grade(_, Grade) :-
    Grade = 'Error'.

% test
% ?- test.
```

This is the error I get:

[screen grab of error on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV6R9.png)

It can see the first line, skips the headers, but is complaining about the what the format it is returning. I have tried to change my code in cert ways like the
read file code to:

```
csv_read_file(InFileName, Rows, []),
```

and the augment implementation started like this:

```
augment([], _).
augment([Row|Rows], OutStream) :-
    Row = [_, ID, Name, HW1, HW2, HW3, Midterm, Final],
```

I am fresh out of ideas as a newbie to the language. I am glad it can see the file and is reading from it based on the output on my terminal, and the fact that it does write the headings to the output file, but that is as far as it goes.

Comment: Identity the line of code with the error. Use e.g. `trace` to step through the program. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was also posted on the SWI-Prolog discussion list and has been answered here: https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/trying-to-print-output-instead-of-true/5479/14

Comment: Thank you @Peter Ludemann. Errors gone and code working perfectly. I responded on thread for those who would like to see the solution.